# Applying Bendixson-Dulac Theorem in circle with radius 3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the system $$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}=y+\frac{1}{5}x^5-x^3,\;\;\; \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=-x+\frac{1}{3}x^2y^3$$ has a centre at the origin, but that there are no closed orbits lying inside the circle whose equation is $x^2 + y^2 = 3$.

I have shown there is a centre at the origin, but am struggling to find an appropriate function to use in the Bendixson-Dulac theorem. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's not clear whether $y+x^5/5-x^3$ means ${y+x^5\over5-x^3}$ or $y+{x^5\over5-x^3}$ or $y+(x^5/5)-x^3$ or something else. Please rewrite your math so it unambiguous.

Comment: Sorry about that - will take more care next time

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the theorem with a general function $\varphi(x,y)$, you would find that:
$$
\frac {\partial (\varphi f)}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial (\varphi g)}{\partial y} = x^2(x^2+y^2-3)\varphi+f\varphi'_x+g\varphi'_y.
$$

The first term is almost everywhere positive in the circle (given $\varphi$ is also almost everywhere positive). If only there was such a function $\varphi(x,y)>0$ which has $\varphi'_x=\varphi'_y=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!